# Getting ClassCastException on unmarshalling an XML file (JAXBContext passes correct class name)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a code that calls this method. I am getting a ClassCastException while unmarshalling. I have passed correct class name while creating `JAXBContext` object.

```
public TestsuiteType parseTestSuiteXML(String path) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestsuiteType.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        TestsuiteType ts = (TestsuiteType) um.unmarshal(new FileReader("/Users/admin/Documents/workspace_Nishant_dev/Practice/xmls/TEST-junit.xml"));
        List<TestcaseType> tcs = ts.getTestcase();
        Iterator<TestcaseType> it = tcs.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            TestcaseType tc = it.next();
            if(tc.getContent().size() == 0) {
                tcs.remove(tc);
            }
        }
        return ts;
    }
```

The exception trace for the above code :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to com.jaxb.testjunit.TestsuiteType
    at com.jaxb.testing.FailureProcessor.parseTestSuiteXML(FailureProcessor.java:49)
    at com.jaxb.testing.FailureProcessor.main(FailureProcessor.java:24)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a `JAXBElement<TestSuiteType>`, not `TestSuiteType`. Your value is in `jaxbElement.getValue()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem so mentioned is solved but still getting an error in TestcaseType tc = it.next();        Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
 at com.jaxb.testing.FailureProcessor.parseTestSuiteXML(FailureProcessor.java:66)
 at com.jaxb.testing.FailureProcessor.main(FailureProcessor.java:27)

Comment: Try `List<TestcaseType> tcs = new LinkedList<TestcaseType>(ts.getTestcase());`. I think `ArrayLists`'s iterator does not support `remove` during iteration. In any case this is now a collections problem, not JAXB.